# How can I select the surfaces of a Cube in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is a simple, but interesting question for Unity 3D Users. My goal is an application, where I can interact (f.e. select 1 of 6 surfaces) with the surfaces of a cube without creating 6 gameobjects and assmebly them to a Cube. Does anyone have an idea or a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would probably be as you described: Build your cube out of multiple independent objects and Colliders etc

---

As alternative I would create the cube mesh yourself, because then you know for sure which triangle belongs to which side. (You could of course also use the default cube and trial and error until you know which triangle index belongs to which side)

```c#
private MeshCollider _collider;

private void Start()
{
    var mesh = new Mesh();
    var verts = new Vector3[]
    {
        new Vector3 (-0.5f; -0.5f; -0.5f),  // index 0
        new Vector3 (-0.5f; 0.5f; -0.5f),   // index 1
        new Vector3 (0.5f; 0.5f; -0.5f),.   // index 2
        new Vector3 (0.5f; -0.5f; -0.5f),   // index 3
        new Vector3 (-0.5f; -0.5f; 0.5f),   // index 4
        new Vector3 (-0.5f; 0.5f; 0.5f),    // index 5
        new Vector3 (0.5f; 0.5f; 0.5f),     // index 6
        new Vector3 (0.5f; -0.5f; 0.5f)     // index 7
    };

    var tris = new int[]
    { 
        // Front
        0, 2, 1,    // index 0
        0, 3, 2,    // index 1

        // Back
        5, 6, 4,   // index 2
        5, 7, 6,    // index 3

        // Top
        3, 6, 2,   // index 4
        3, 7, 6,   // index 5

        // Bottom
        4, 1, 5    // index 6
        4, 0, 1,   // index 7

        // Left
        4, 3, 0,   // index 8
        4, 7, 3    // index 8

        // Righ
        1, 6, 5,   // index 10
        1, 2, 6    // index 11
    };

    mesh.vertices = verts;
    mesh.triangles = tris;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();

    var obj = new GameObject ("Cube", typeof(MeshFilter), typeof (MeshRenderer));
    obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = new Material(Shader.Find("Specular"));
    obj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    _collider = obj.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    _collider.mesh = mesh;

    obj.transform.position = Camera.main.position + Vector3.forward * 7;
    obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(45, 45, 45);
}
```

And then simply use [`RaycastHit.triangleIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html) to determine which triangle you are hitting -> you'll know the side by mapping the indices to the according side e.g.

```c#
enum Side
{
    Front,
    Back,
    Top,
    Bottom,
    Left,
    Right
}

Dictionary<int,Side> triangleIdxToSide = new Dictionary<int,Side>
{
    {0, Side.Front},
    {1, Side.Front},

    {2, Side.Back},
    {3, Side.Back},

    {4, Side.Top},
    {5, Side.Top},

    {6, Side.Bottom},
    {7, Side.Bottom},

    {8, Side.Left},
    {9, Side.Left},

    {10, Side.Right},
    {11, Side.Right}
}

void Update ()
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if(_collider.Raycast(ray, out var hit))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Currently pointing on {triangleIdxToSide[hit.triangleIndex]} of the cube", this);
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*